# Tagging a product based on price

Tags: r

I have a dataset like below and I want to create a new column(product_type) and want to tag the products based on their price.

B/W 0 and 499 - mass

b/w 500 and 1499 - aspiring

1500 and above - premium

product_id        price

```
1            50
2            500
3            1500
```

product_id   price   product_type

```
1         50     mass
2         500    aspiring
3         1500   premium
```

Do I have to use k-means for clustering or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried ?ifelse()?

Comment: Look into ?cut or ?ifelse

Answer (score 0):

with data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(product_id, price)

DT[, product_type := ifelse(price<=499, "mass", ifelse(price>=500 & price<=1499, "aspiring", ifelse(price>=1500, "premium", "")))]
```